# how to retrieve MHTML file information using powershell command

Tags: powershell

I have a mhtml file as test.mht
data present in test.mht is as below

Field    String
Name     Carpool
Type     ModernApplication
Language     en-us English
Category     Tools
IsTrial  false
GUID     712ec8b1-0370-4ed5-b1ac-f0eca1f64348
Markets
MarketName
United States
Strings
Field    String

question:
how to retrieve the GUID information using powershell command

ex:
$GetGUID =  [load mhtm file]
write-host $GetGUID.GUID
should print : 712ec8b1-0370-4ed5-b1ac-f0eca1f64348

Comment: Downvoted since there has been no response to the only supplied answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with a regular expression:

```
(Get-Content .\Test.mht) -Match "^(?<=GUID\s+).+$" | Out-Null; Write-Host $matches[0];
```

Comment: $ID = @()
[array]$ID = (Get-Content C:\Test.mht) -Match "^(?<=GUID\s+).+$" | Out-Null
Write-Host $ID and also tried with Write-Host $ID[0] but it prints nothing, could you please correct it?

Comment: (Get-Content .\Test.mht) -Match "^(?<=GUID\s+).+$" | Out-Null;
$ID = $matches[0];